# How to reference a button created in Storyboard?

Tags: button, storyboard

I created some buttons in Storyboard and would like to change their size and position programmatically based on user input.  How do I reference them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could instantiate them in the control itself, initialising them in a hidden state, then make them visible in the storyboard. That way they'll be accessible from within the control, which is where I assume you'll want to change the buttons' size and position programatically.